# Windbg symbols for dbghelp

Tags: windows, windbg

I having trouble with the dbghelp.pdb after installing Win SDK 8.1.

`SYMSRV:

c:\symbol\dbghelp.pdb\B4CDB1D5A1A545249FA397667D3925671\dbghelp.pdb not found
SYMSRV:  http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/dbghelp.pdb/B4CDB1D5A1A545249FA397667D3925671/dbghelp.pdb not found
DBGHELP: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\dbghelp.pdb - file not found`

I have uninstalled the SDK and re install. Do you think the issue is with the Microsoft Public symbol server?

Answer (score 1):

Spoke to microsoft below is the answer I got.
'Dbghelp isn't indexed. We know, it can't be fixed'